# Compile shared library linux gcc/g++ cpp

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, shared-libraries, ld

I have successfully compiled and created a shared object, but I'm not sure if it is truly shared and linked/analog to DLL.Could you tell me if it is right?
    I have shared.h, main.cpp, nameOfLib.cpp.

```
shared.h

#ifndef SHARED_H
   #define SHARED_H
   int helpingLib();
#endif

main.cpp

#include "shared.h"
#pragma once

int main(){
 helpingLib();
 return 0;
}

nameOfLib.cpp

#pragma once
int helpingLib(){ return 20;}

Console:
g++ -shared -fPIC nameOfLib.cpp -o renameTo.so
//create local var 
export $MY_LD_PATH = /home/student/Documents/Total/LinuxXlib/renameTo.so
g++ main.cpp -Wl,$MY_LD_PATH -o executable
```

First of all is it is a truly shareable library? 

It works correctly, even with sophisticated cpp code in nameOfLib.cpp

Comment: Yes!! If you write a complex library, you may want to control exported symbols visibility: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility.

Comment: Yes it is truly shared, when you execute your code ld-linux.so will make a mmap system call to get your library code section mapped into your process virtual memory: the kernel will load the file in the RAM and map it to the process address space. Then if you start an other program using your library, ld-linux.so (the elf interpreter) will ask once again the kernel to map this section: the kernel will not reload a second copy of your file into physical memory, it will use the one already loaded and just produce a new mapping to the memory address space of the second process.

Comment: Oliv, can you also explain how to use a multithreading shared  library, so that the process which runs main() will have to delegate shared library code to the next process?

Comment: I am not sure  I have understood your question. But from what I know which is approximative, libpthread use the `clone` system call to create new thread, so every thread run in the same address space. All threads of a same process share the same  dynamic symbol table, and the same mapping of a shared library. So if you load a dynamic library in one thread, this library will be visible to the others.

Comment: It is exactly what I've needed, thank you Oliv, by the way, where did you get all this information? Could you recommend a book?

Comment: "The linux programming interface" by M.Kerrisk, also all the specs SYTEM V Application Binary Interface, the ELF specification, and most instructive dissassembling!. Looking inside the libc source is also realy instructive.

Comment: (look comment above) Also you can list system calls (or libc wrapper's) by invoking `apropos -s 2` and then navigating through the man pages, also https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/. Honestly, I had more difficulties to retrieve information on this subject than on sensible rocket techonlogies I used to work on! That changed my mind about the signification of the term "open" !!

Comment: I'm sorry for it, didn't wanted to cause such troubles. Thank you!

Comment: But your not causing trouble? I am sorry if I made you feel like you were a source of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure if it is truly shared

Yes, it is.

Your command line to link against this shared library is wrong though. Do this instead:

```
g++ main.cpp -o executable /home/student/Documents/Total/LinuxXlib/renameTo.so
```